# Starting signalR many times

Tags: jquery, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm getting in trouble with SignalR because of calling `.start()` multiple times.

Here's my jQuery code which is working:

```
var signalR = $.connection.chat;

var signIn = function() {
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      signalR.server.signIn()
   })
};

var signOut = function() {
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      signalR.server.signOut()
   })
};

var privateChat = function() {
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      signalR.server.privateChat()
   })
};
```

I have found a solution to improve the code like this:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   var signIn = function() {
      signalR.server.signIn()
   };

   var signOut = function() {
      signalR.server.signOut()
   };

   var privateChat = function() {
      signalR.server.privateChat()
   };
})
```

What I want to achieve is: write `$.connection.hub.start().done()` only 1 time as `global` (needn't be restarted).

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you want... Your second solution seems pretty much there except that your 3 methods are not accessible outside the scope of the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. I thinks some code is missing to fully understand your question but this should work:

```
// get chat hub
var signalR = $.connection.chat;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  // connect hub to server
  signalR.server.signIn();
  signalR.server.signOut();
  signalR.server.privateChat();
});
```